# How can I restrict Janus API to accessible only for a specific domain

Tags: javascript, api, janus, janus-gateway

How can Restrict API access only for particular domain. I mean when I visit API to be on example.com then only it should be allow to send or receive streams on remaining it should not be.

please help me as I new to here.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit cors configuration in **janus.transport.http.jcfg** file on your janus instance.

```
cors: {
    #allow_origin = "http://foo.examplea"
}
```